# How to merge collection and Query builder then use paginate on it Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, pagination, builder

I have a builder object and a collection and i want to combine them and use paginate of laravel.

How can i do that ?

```
public function getRequests(){
        $closedRequests = request::join('request_logs', 'request_logs.request_id', '=', 'requests.id')
                    ->select("requests.id", "requests.user_id", "requests.form_type", "requests.created_at", "requests.request_status")
                    ->whereNotIn('request_status', [-2, 0])
                    ->where('request_logs.user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        $processingRequests = request::select("requests.id", "requests.user_id", "requests.form_type", "requests.created_at", "requests.request_status")
                         ->where('request_status', 0)
                         ->get()
                         ->filter(function ($request) {
                               return FormsController::checkUserPermissionToConsultForm($request, true);

        });
        $closedRequests = $closedRequests->union($processingRequests)
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->paginate(5);
        return $closedRequests;
    }
```

The function above is what i tried to do but it generate an error saying

```
Call to a member function getBindings() on array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no default method available to do such things in Laravel. What you can do is you can make one by using the `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` or `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` depending on your need. `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` refers to the `simplePaginate()` method where `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` refers to `paginate` method.

Another way could be converting the builder result into the collection. Then merge the builder collection and the `$processingRequests` collection and use `forPage()` method which is also a collection method to generate pagination with some modification.

Here are the references:

Custom Pagination: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

forPage:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forpage
https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-paginating-collections-with-forpage

Comment: Would that be efficient if i have 20K item in each collection ?

Comment: It's totally a different question, you code like that way. Pagination is nothing but adding limit and offset to query passed to the database. In your code you're already fetching all data and then filtering, it will definitely take time on a larger dataset. In such cases you can use chunk() method or cursor() method to handle such situation